# LDAP user registration gives "no global superior knowledge" error while DN is defined as per .ldif file

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I am using LDAP for user management and I have configured it with Spring Boot Ldap. User login (authentication) is working properly and now, I am trying to register a new user and inserting an entry in LDAP using ldapTemplate.bind() method.

**Registration**

```
public String create(UserResponsePojo userResponsePojo) {
        try {
              Name dn = LdapNameBuilder
                      .newInstance()
                      .add("o", "company")
                      .add("ou", "department")
                      .build();

                    DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter();
                    context.setDn(dn);
                    context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[]{"top", "person", "inetOrgPerson"});
                    context.setAttributeValue("cn", userResponsePojo.getUsername());
                    context.setAttributeValue("sn", userResponsePojo.getLastname());
                    context.setAttributeValue("description", userResponsePojo.getUserrole());
                    context.setAttributeValue("mail", userResponsePojo.getUid());
                    context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", userResponsePojo.getPassword());

                    ldapTemplate.bind(context);

                    return "success";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "failed";
                }   
    }
```

**ldif file**

```
# id=00000001
dn: o=company
objectClass: organization
structuralObjectClass: organization
o: company
entryCSN: 20130409162114.626166Z#000000#000#000000
entryUUID: 3e7f8668-357d-1032-8a6b-c5bcf7f703f0
creatorsName: cn=Manager,o=company
createTimestamp: 20130409162114Z
modifiersName: cn=Manager,o=company
modifyTimestamp: 20130409162114Z
contextCSN: 20130702105648.506150Z#000000#000#000000
contextCSN: 20191018052018.692119Z#000000#001#000000
contextCSN: 20191018044350.858888Z#000000#002#000000
contextCSN: 20191018053729.621549Z#000000#003#000000

# id=00000002
dn: ou=department,o=company
objectClass: organizationalUnit
structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: department
entryCSN: 20130409162455.623488Z#000000#000#000000
entryUUID: c2390a06-357d-1032-8a6c-c5bcf7f703f0
creatorsName: cn=Manager,o=company
createTimestamp: 20130409162455Z
modifiersName: cn=Manager,o=company
modifyTimestamp: 20130409162455Z

# id=00000003
dn: mail=abc@gmail.com,ou=department,o=company
businessCategory: unset
sn: unset
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9RTFoVUNEM1pPc3RBQ2g4ZHWlVDTk80QWN6ajk3aHFC
mail: abc@gmail.com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: 842a22b0-a8c6-1032-9ba8-e1e428e5443b
creatorsName: cn=Manager,o=company
createTimestamp: 20130903092528Z
cn: abc
description: Member
entryCSN: 20130903092528.695993Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=Manager,o=company
modifyTimestamp: 20130903092528Z

# id=00000004
dn: mail=xyz@gmail.com,ou=department,o=company
uid: unset
mail: xyz@gmail.com
sn: unset
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9OXU3aEFVQkthdZMb284ZWQrNkthdUtrN1NDUnAraDFU
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: eafcbd14-a8ca-1032-9bac-e1e428e5443b
creatorsName: cn=Manager,o=company
createTimestamp: 20130903095658Z
cn: xyz
description: Member
businessCategory: e-Governance
entryCSN: 20130927145536.344831Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=Manager,o=company
modifyTimestamp: 20130927145536Z
```

When, ldapTemplate.bind() is called it throws error **LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior knowledge**

```
org.springframework.ldap.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior knowledge]; nested exception is javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior knowledge]; remaining name 'ou=department,o=company'
```

I searched for solution over web and found that this error occurs when we try to insert an user in some directory which is not available in ldif file but as I can see, I am trying to use same directory which is also available in ldif file as well.
I tried many DN combinations but didn't get required solution. Please guide me through this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `              Name dn = LdapNameBuilder
                      .newInstance()
                      .add("o", "company")
                      .add("ou", "department")
                      .build();`

Creates a DN 'ou=department,o=company' , but I guess you want to create an entry with 'mail=VALUE,ou=department,o=company'.

Comment: Yes, I want to create a new entry with 'mail=VALUE,ou=department,o=company' and that's why, I also provided Name dn = LdapNameBuilder .newInstance() .add("o", "company") .add("ou", "department") .add("mail", "VALUE") .build(); as well. But still I am getting the same error

Comment: 'no global superior knowledge' seems like an error from OpenLDAP directory server. Does it work when you try to add the entry via 'ldapmodify'?

Comment: I tried `ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,o=company" -W -f  test1.ldif` for inserting data via command line and it was executed successfully but still when I am trying with JAVA code it is throwing same exception everytime.